Access_token of OAuth 2.0 is not working how to resolve this issue?

wanted to know root cause and how to resolve this please help me out.
I tried to access one of my custom route after the oAuth2.0 authentication. I was expecting to get the response of 200 but due to invalid_grant I wasn't able to move ahead with the flow because the authentication itself is failing over here.

please edit your question include [example]  try to delete that file and authorize your application again.  Invalid grant normally means your refresh token is bad.  if its not that then check the time on your server is in sync with NTP
